# Debug - Step Into (F11) does not go straight to the function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, debugging

When I'm debugging my code and I'm on a line that will call a function that I created (explode):

```
vector<string> parte = explode(linha, ";");
```

In this line I want the debugger to go into the 'explode' function.

However, when pressing F11, the debugger goes through HUNDREDS of lines from the `xstring, xutility, xmemory0, xstddef` and others files so only after all this journey, go to my 'explode' function.

Why does this occur?

And how to avoid this? F11 might go straight to my function and not be 'strolling' through all these intermediaries?

Comment: Are they perhaps dependencies?

Comment: Have you enabled "Just my code" in the debugger options?

Comment: Effectively the same question as [Debug - Step Into (F11) does not go straight to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629605/debug-step-into-f11-does-not-go-straight-to-the-function). Pity there doesn't seem to be a good answer for this that you haven't already tried.

Comment: @user4581301, as you can see, this question was in superuser.com and was migrated to here without my knowledge. This question was posted there for the first, but as there was no responses, I recreated the question here, a little more elaborated. Anyway, it's a VS 2017 bug and it's being analysed by the VS staff.

Comment: Per the comment above, and given that the "duplicate" has been deleted, I'm voting to reopen this question. (Let me also ping @Chad, since they're the one who dupe-hammered this; if they agree, they can reopen this question directly.)

Comment: @ilmari_karonen thanks for the heads up

Comment: [Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx), have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, one reason would be that your `explode` function takes parameters of another type (for ex. `std::string`) which itself will call many function if you do **F11**.

Usually, in such case when you enter a function you don't want to trace use **Shift + F11** (Step out) instead so you directly get back to the calling site and then you repeat that for any other intermediate call. In some cases **F10** could works to reduce the number of steps.

Sometime you could modify the code to make more friendly for debugging for exemple by using some temporary variables.

An alternative however is to put a breakpoint inside your `explode` function. However, this works well only if there is only a few call before the one that interest you. Sometime, you could put a condition on the breakpoint or at the caller location. Other time, setting a second breakpoint when the first one is hit could also works.

With a few tricks like that, you can greatly reduce the number of extra steps.

Also limit the number of debugging windows that are visible if you don't need them as some are relatively slow (for ex. threads) and without them sometime, you can simply press F11 a few times until you hit desired function.